# Getting an error while logging in to SharePoint 2013 using Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, sharepoint-2013, identityserver4

I'm getting an error while trying to login to SharePoint 2013 using Identity Server 4, this is the error "This method can only be called after the authentication event `at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_LogonUserIdentity() +258`".

The error happens when I host the identity server mvc core app on IIS. when run it from the Visual Studio, it works fine. can someone advise or help.

Edited:

This is the SignIn action in the Account Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var vm = await _account.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

        if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
        {
            // only one option for logging in
            return await ExternalLogin(vm.ExternalProviders.First().AuthenticationScheme, returnUrl);
        }
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Query["culture"])) ViewBag.QueryString = Request.QueryString.Value.Replace("&culture=en", "").Replace("&culture=ar", "") + "&culture=" + Request.Query["culture"];
        else ViewBag.QueryString = Request.QueryString.Value.Replace("&culture=en", "").Replace("&culture=ar", "") + "&culture=en";
        return View(vm);
    }

 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // validate username/password against in-memory store
            if (_users.CheckPassword(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                // only set explicit expiration here if persistent. 
                // otherwise we reply upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                {
                    props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                    };
                };

                // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                var user = _users.Find(model.Username);
                await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.UserName, props);
                // deleteCookie();
              //  HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("FedAuth", "", new CookieOptions() { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) });
                // make sure the returnUrl is still valid, and if yes - redirect back to authorize endpoint
                if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }

                return Redirect("~/");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
        }
        ViewBag.QueryString = Request.QueryString.Value;
        // something went wrong, show form with error
        var vm = await _account.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

This is the full Error details

```html
<html><head>
        <title>This method can only be called after the authentication event.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><h1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width="100%" size="1" color="silver"></h1>

            <h2> <i>This method can only be called after the authentication event.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: This method can only be called after the authentication event.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tbody><tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody></table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tbody><tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>
[InvalidOperationException: This method can only be called after the authentication event.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_LogonUserIdentity() +5017679
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetRequestData(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, Boolean allowCreate) +203
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.InitContextWeb(HttpContext context, SPWeb web) +140
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context) +842
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.RedirectValidateInternal(String url, SPWeb web, HttpContext context, Boolean isTrusted) +301
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.DetermineRedirectUrl(String urlProposed, SPRedirectFlags flags, HttpContext context, SPWeb overrideWeb, String queryString, String&amp; urlRedirect) +736
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.Redirect(String url, SPRedirectFlags flags, HttpContext context, String queryString) +77
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.OnSignedIn(EventArgs eventArgs) +579
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest request) +736
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +324
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +139
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +92
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody></table>

            <br>

            <hr width="100%" size="1" color="silver">

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1087.0

            </font>

    

<!-- 
[InvalidOperationException]: This method can only be called after the authentication event.
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_LogonUserIdentity()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetRequestData(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, Boolean allowCreate)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.InitContextWeb(HttpContext context, SPWeb web)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.RedirectValidateInternal(String url, SPWeb web, HttpContext context, Boolean isTrusted)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.DetermineRedirectUrl(String urlProposed, SPRedirectFlags flags, HttpContext context, SPWeb overrideWeb, String queryString, String& urlRedirect)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.Redirect(String url, SPRedirectFlags flags, HttpContext context, String queryString)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.OnSignedIn(EventArgs eventArgs)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: @moritzg I haved added the authentication logic in the question , please let me know if you need more details

Comment: The full stack trace of the error would be helpful too!

Comment: I added error details and error full stack

Comment: Ok strange error, I had similar problems when switching between `Release` and `Debug`, so I suggest you clean your project, and try to run it locally with `Release`? And check the configuration differences between `Release` and `Debug`

Comment: It works fine on both of Debug and Release when running the project from VS but it happens when I host the application on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue by modifying the redirect Url of SharePoint site and removing default.aspx from the url to be http://{{SP Site}}/_trust instead of http://{{SP Site}}/_trust/default.aspx